# Redirect 301 specific pages and the rest to just one page

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

First I need to redirect these pages to another page in a different domain

```
Redirect 301 /example1 http://newdomain.com/test1
Redirect 301 /example2 http://newdomain.com/random1
```

Note the pages are not the same in the new domain (e.g., /example1 to /test1)

After that, I need redirect the rest of the pages to `newdomain.com`

E.g., Redirect 301 (everything else) to http://newdomain.com

Answer (score 2):

Try below rule, using `mod rewrite` I am assuming you have mod rewrite enabled.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^example1$ http://newdomain.com/test1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^example2$ http://newdomain.com/random1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(example1|example2)
RewriteRule ^ http://newdomain.com [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Also, is there a way to not specify the pages in this line `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(example1|example2)` because there's many of them

Comment: Well try again my edited rule, please specify your full requirements at the time of asking the question because so is not a code writing service you might have to try it for your self or ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use **mod-alias** , you can use these redirects :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/example1/?$ http://example.com/test1
RedirectMatch 301 ^/example2/?$ http://example.com/random1
#redirect everything else to the homepage of example.com
RedirectMatch ^.+$ http://example.com/
```

Clear your browser cache before testing these redirects.

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://newdomain.com/ [R=301]
```

Comment: Sorry but this just redirects everything

Comment: @IMB that was just an example, you need to modify that according to your needs